# splice html tags in html string

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

i am using htmlagility pack to remove `<br>` tag at the start and end position but the below code is removing from all the places.

HTML string:

```
 <p><br><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span><br></p>
```

below is the code where i am removing the br tags

```
    using HtmlAgilityPack;

    var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(input.HTMLString);
    var rootNode = document.DocumentNode;
    var nodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("//br");
    if (nodes != null)
    {
        foreach (var brTag in nodes)
            brTag.Remove();
        this.HTMLString = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    }
```

and i am expecting the result string looks like this

```
 <p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>
```

instead getting string in `this.HTMLString` like this as below

```
  <p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>
```

Could any one please help on how to remove `br` tag only at the start and at the end of string and not in between string and i am using HTMLAgility pack library

Comment: You remove first <br>, after you check first tag and search the close tag (ex. </tag>), you check the index of this and confront the index of tag with next </br>, if the closetag is minor then </br>  you remove </br>.

Comment: there will be no closing tag in the string i was mentioned and all are `<br>` tags itself

Comment: You read all line in the document or one for times?

Comment: all lines first and then identify nodes and remove the identified nodes (`br`) , but here i don't want to remove the tags in between html string. I need to remove the tags(`br`) only at the start position of string and end position of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your HTML is always within a `<p>` element or if the number of `<br />` elements are different from case to case. If it's not different and you can depend on the outer element being the same, you can use this to get the first and last `<br/>` elements.

**Option #1** - When parent element (`p` in this case) is known and number of `br` elemnts are known (3 in this case).

```
string html = "<p><br><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span><br></p>";
string outHtml = string.Empty;

var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
var rootNode = document.DocumentNode;
var firstBrNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("//p/br[1]");
var lastBrNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("//p/br[last()]");

firstBrNode?.Remove();
lastBrNode?.Remove();
outHtml = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

output:

`<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>`

---

**Option #2** - When parent element is not known and the number of `br` tags is not known, and it's assumed if one `br` element is present it will be retained in the HTML.

```
string html = "<p><br><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span><br></p>";
// string html = "<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>";
string outHtml = string.Empty;
var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
var rootNode = document.DocumentNode;
// count all br nodes so we can bypass removal of br if there is only one in HTML
var brNodeCount = rootNode.SelectNodes("//br") == null ? 0 : rootNode.SelectNodes("//br").Count;
// get the parent node of the br element to be used in the xpath when we remove
// the br elements this will allow for different parent elements other than the `p` element
var parentNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("//br/parent::*");
// only removes br elements if more than one in HTML, assumes if 1 br element is present it's in the middle and will not be removed
if (brNodeCount > 1)
{ 
    var firstBrNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode($"//{parentNode.Name}/br[1]");
    var lastBrNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode($"//{parentNode.Name}/br[last()]");
    firstBrNode?.Remove();
    lastBrNode?.Remove();
}
outHtml = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

output:

`<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>`

---

**Option #3** - Takes into account the index of the first and last text nodes and removes all `br` elements that sit 'outside' them. Text nodes that contain an empty or an all white-space value are ignored.

```
// removes all br tags with an index before the first text node and
// all br tags with an index after the end of the last text node,
// any br tags between are not removed
private string RemoveStartAndEndBrTags(string html)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(html)) return html;
    var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(html);
    var rootNode = document.DocumentNode;
    // get first and last text nodes, excluding any only containing white-space
    var allNonEmptyTextNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("//text()[not(self::text()[not(normalize-space())])]");
    if (allNonEmptyTextNodes == null || allNonEmptyTextNodes.Count == 0) return html;
    var firstTextNode = allNonEmptyTextNodes[0];
    var lastTextNode = allNonEmptyTextNodes[allNonEmptyTextNodes.Count - 1];
    // get the parent node of the first br element, it will be used when we remove the br elements,
    // this will allow for different parent elements other than the `p` element
    var parentNode = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("//br/parent::*");
    if (parentNode == null) return html;
    var allBrNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes($"//{parentNode.Name}/br");
    foreach (var brNode in allBrNodes)
    {
        if (brNode == null) continue;
        // check index of br nodes against first and last text nodes
        // and remove br nodes that sit outside text nodes
        if (brNode.OuterStartIndex <= firstTextNode.OuterStartIndex
            || brNode.OuterStartIndex >= lastTextNode.OuterStartIndex + lastTextNode.OuterLength)
        { 
            brNode.Remove();
        }
    }
    return document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

Test HTML Input:

```
<p><br><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span><br></p>
<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>
<p><span>MERV 9 <br>Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>
<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters<br> </span></p>
<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters<br></span></p>
```

Test HTML Output:

```
<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>
<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>
<p><span>MERV 9 <br>Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>
<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p
<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters</span></p>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, and `<p>` might not be placed all the cases and will this work if `<p>` is not present and if there is only <br> tag in between string

Comment: Sorry it is not working for this string `<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>`

Comment: sorry again, i am looking for irrespective number of `br` tags in the middle of the string and would like to remove only the `br` at the start of html string and at the end of html string

Comment: Option #2 should do what you want. It works with both of the HTML examples you posted.

Comment: is the above second option will works for this as well `<p><span>MERV 9 <br>Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>`, in this case this should preserve both the tags actually. the `br` count is two which are placed in between strings

Comment: sorry it is removing all and the output is coming as this one `<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>` where as input like as this `<p><span>MERV 9<br> Cartridge<br><b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>`

Comment: and it is working for this type of input `<p><span>MERV 9<br> Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>` and getting output like as this `<p><span>MERV 9<br> Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>`

Comment: and it is not working if we have more than one `br` tags in between html strings, could you please help suggest any ideas on this thanks

Comment: if there is no `br` tag at the start or at the end `br` and it is trimming all br tags in between string and i have given this as input `<p><span>MERV 9<br> Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b><br>Prefilters </span></p>` and it is coming output like as this `<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>`

Comment: Could you please help me on this issue

Comment: could you please help on this last condition and getting all br tags stripped off from the string if there is no br tag at the start and end

Comment: sorry this is not working even we have one `<br>` tag that is placed at the starting of the string kind of this input `<p><span><br>MERV 9 Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>` and the results are coming as same `<p><span><br>MERV 9 Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>`

Comment: What determines the start and end of your HTML? If there is only one `br`, at what point in the HTML is it no longer a start `br`? At what point in the HTML does it become an end `br`?

Comment: the start point of br is before the starting of the initial text node and end of the br is after the last text node

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the start point of br is the `br` tag appeared before the first node and end point of `br` tag is to identify after the last textnode

Comment: oh sorry just came from lunch please give me one sec i will test now

Comment: If i have given this input `<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>` i am getting an exception like System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

parentNode was null.

Comment: i will be expecting same output as input because there are no `br` tags before the first textnode and after that last text node

Comment: I didn't add the error checking for null node references related to the first, last and br nodes, you may want to add null checks in case the nodes are not found. If a node is null you can return the HTML that was passed in.

Comment: if any of the node is null we need to return as it is i believe

Comment: That sounds reasonable, just add the null checking and return the HTML if a null is found.

Comment: in this case parentnode is null so it is better to leave as it is or do you want me process below as well

Comment: and in this case `<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters<br> </span></p>` it is failing and it is not removing last `br` tag

Comment: Could you please help on this condition

Comment: The HTML you posted, `<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b><br>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters<br> </span></p>` has that last `br` node before the last `text` node (which is an empty space). So, this `br` is not `outside` of the last text node and therefore is excluded based on the rules established.

Comment: yeah at the same time last br node after the text `prefilters` text  `Prefilters<br>` and this `br` tag is need to be removed, because this is node after last text node

Comment: If the parent node is null then it means there are no `br` nodes in the HTML, if there are no `br` nodes there is nothing to remove and therefore you can simply return the HTML as it was received. Edited answer option 3 to include parent node null check.

Comment: is there any way i can achieve the last condition to pass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230057/discussion-between-enigma-state-and-quaabaam).

Comment: could we please continue in chat

Comment: could you please help on this last issue

Comment: I've updated option 3 to handle the last scenario. I think it works, I didn't get much time to test it. Good luck!

Comment: sorry for update after long and i am checking with this condition where i have given this as input `<p><span><br>MERV 9 Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span><br></p>` and the below is coming as output  `<p><span><br>MERV 9 Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>` .. I believe it needs to strip the starting `<br>` tag as well because it is the `br` tag before the first node

Comment: it looks like the `br` will present in any place before the textnode, here it present after the `span` node.. I was expecting this one as output `<p><span>MERV 9 Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span></p>`

Comment: I have not seen this as example in your post as well `<p><span><br>MERV 9 Cartridge<b>&nbsp;</b>Prefilters </span><br></p>`but yeah the `br` tag is presented before the text node

Comment: is there any way to grab all `br` nodes before the first text node and after the last text node irrespective of parent element and this is not working for `var allBrNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes($"//{parentNode.Name}/br");`

Comment: never mind i found solution for this and thanks for the support

Comment: just one more query how to remove all empty nodes from the above nodes having blank lines, if there is html that is having blank lines i need to smash them all

Comment: could you please let me know how to remove if there is input like `<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>` would like remove all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230276/discussion-between-enigma-state-and-quaabaam).